# Spring MVC, MongoDB and Eclipse Mars. How to use

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

Need a example of using Spring MVC, MongoDB with CRUD operation on Eclipse Mars 2.

I tried many example from internet, but they didn;t specified about placement of files. Placement of file is important part of any web project. Please specify them.

As I am learning , I have used Maven and installed all latest jars

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think about spring-data-mongodb . Using mongotemplate its very easy to manipulate your db using spring app.

Step 1: add dependency to your pom.xml

```
 <!-- MongoDB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Step 2: you need to define bean in your configuartion xml file. i.e. servlet-context.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">


<mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="192.168.1.85" port="27017" />
    <mongo:db-factory id="mongoFactory" host="192.168.1.85"
        port="27017" dbname="xxxxx" />

<beans:bean id="mongoTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="mongoFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

<!-- Your configuration here-->
```

Note: Remove unnecessary part in your case.

Step 3: You can autowired mongo template in your DAO layer.

```
@Autowired
    @Qualifier("mongoTemplate")
    private MongoTemplate mt;
```

you can find ,update,insert using mt
e.g. mt.find(new Query(Criteria.where("id").is("i123")));

Hope so it will help you..